# How to appear google map api v2 in a dialog, when i click a button

Tags: android, dialog, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm in stuck. I have a custom list with custom list adapter. Every list item has a button if I click to this button a dialog pop up what should contain the google map (later with marker). I've tried to assign the fragment to a SupportMapFragment, but the Android Studio says me, "getSupportFragmentManager() cannot resolve method". My question is how to put into a dialog this map(fragment)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="hu.bognaroliver.bajaintezemnyek.CustomListAdapter">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This was the map.

```
package hu.bognaroliver.bajaintezemnyek;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;


public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Institute> implements    OnMapReadyCallback
{
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ImageView instituteLogo;
private TextView instituteName;
private TextView instituteAddress;
private TextView instituteCloseTime;
private ImageView instituteType;
private TextView instituteStatus;
private ImageView mapView;
private Dialog mDialog;
private final Context context = getContext();

public CustomListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Institute> item)
{
    super(context, 0, item);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
{
    Institute institute = getItem(position);

    if(convertView == null)
        convertView =       LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.institute_item, parent, false);

    instituteLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.instituteLogo);
    instituteName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.instituteName);
    instituteAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.instituteAddress);
    instituteCloseTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.instituteCloseTime);
    instituteType = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.instituteType);
    instituteStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.instituteStatus);
    mapView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    instituteLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.cba_logo);
    instituteName.setText(institute.getName());
    instituteAddress.setText(institute.getAddress());
    instituteCloseTime.setText("30 perc múlva");
    instituteType.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_48dp);
    instituteStatus.setText(institute.getStatus().toString());
    mapView.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_icon);


    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupoortMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    //MapFragment mapFragment = ((MapFragment) findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    //mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mDialog = new Dialog(context);
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_map);
    mDialog.setTitle("Title...");



    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
    TextView text = (TextView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");

    mapView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mDialog.show();
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map)
{
    //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH GOOGLEMAP
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    map.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new        LatLng(46.1811211,18.9542073) , 13.0f) );
    map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

}
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a shortcut way to do this by using google MapView

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="hu.bognaroliver.bajaintezemnyek.CustomListAdapter">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ok"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ok"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

on itemclick show dialog

```
new Dialog(getContext()) {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
            MapView map = findViewById(R.id.map_view);
            map.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    //add marker here
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(lng)
                            .title("Marker Title"));

                    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(
                        new OnMarkerClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                            // Marker source is clicked

                            return true;
                        }

                    });
                }
            });


            findViewById(R.id.btn_ok).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //do something

                }
            });
            findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel).setOnClickListener(new         View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dismiss();

                }
            });

        }
    }.show();
```

try this one

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogmap);
dialog.show();
GoogleMap googleMap;


MapView mMapView = (MapView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());          

mMapView = (MapView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mMapView.onCreate(dialog.onSaveInstanceState());
mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately
googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
```

Comment: It is almost works, but when I click to the button inside the list item, the screen becomes grey only, like the dialog wants to load in. But in this case nothing appear on the screen just a grey "layer".

Comment: 2nd one might help u

Comment: Have you solved this? I try using your solution but it wont work. What did you do? @BognárOlivér

Answer (score 0):

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(lng)
                .title("Marker Title"));

                mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                       // Marker source is clicked   

                        return true;
                    }

                });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In present the marker is not the main problem.